# Ionic - Set Navbar Class to bar-assertive not working

Tags: ionic-framework, navbar

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Ionic Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
OS:
Node Version: v5.5.0

```
<ion-view view-title="Change Header" class="bar-assertive">


  <ion-content>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-radio ng-model="color" ng-value="'bar-stable'">Stable</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="color" ng-value="'bar-assertive'">Assertive</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio ng-model="color" ng-value="'bar-calm'">Calm</ion-radio>
    </ion-list>
    <span ng-bind="color"></span>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

As you can see the code above, I add `class="bar-assertive"` to ion-view tags, and the navbar should change color to red, but the result remain the same with previous. There's no change in background-color of the navbar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the nav-bar-color in your index with this code:

```
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive"></ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

If you need to customize nav-bar (i.e. apply a specific class) add an `<ion-nav-bar>` tag inside the `<ion-view>` you want with a custom nav bar:

```
<ion-nav-bar align-title="right" class="bar-positive">...</ion-nav-bar>
```

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/XXeydY

But if you want to set different color for each tabs/view you could also use ngClass and $stateChangeSuccess:

```
  <ion-nav-bar ng-class="headerClass"></ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

In your app (in run section) you have to set $scope.headerClass according to the current state:

```
.run(function($state, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState) {
    if (toState.name == "xyz") {
      $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-positive';
    } else {
      $rootScope.headerClass = 'bar-assertive';
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I already try insert another ion-nav-bar and the nav-bar will replace the existing nav-bar thus will also remove the menu-button

Comment: check the codePen I shared in my answer, maybe it could help you

Comment: In that example (codePen) the first view (home.html) has a custom style (color, title alignment,...) and so has a custom `<ion-nav-bar>` which repeats the `<ion-nav-back-button>` and `<ion-nav-buttons>` (in order to keep them in the view)